# SQL Server Time format in 23:59:59 and not 00:00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code. I would like the second (to) date in time format '23:59:59' and not '00:00:00' . How can this be achieved please?

```
declare @Date datetime 
declare @StartDate datetime 
declare @EndDate DateTime

set @date = GetDate()
Set @StartDate = DATEADD(M, DATEDIFF(M,0,@date),0)
set @EndDate = DATEADD(DD,DATEDIFF(DD,0, @date),0)

select @StartDate,@EndDate
```

Comment: One little hack is set @endate = format(@date,'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59')   That said, there are some risks like excluding milliseconds

Comment: @marc_s. the example value you provided is seconds rather than milliseconds. Did you mean `23:59:59.997` and the next value is `00:00:00.000`?

Comment: @DanGuzman: of course - you're absolutely right.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate it. I think Joel's answer below might be the safer/cleaner option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DateTime type doesn't use text internally at all. Rather, it is a **binary** type, and anything you see indicating otherwise is a convenience of the tooling. The best strategy for this kind of thing is leaving the value as a binary type for *as long as possible*, and only format for display to the user at the last possible moment.

In the case of an end date, where you are given a value on the last day of a range and you want it to include the full day, your best option is to adjust for the **beginning of the next day**, and then use an **exclusive** *less than* comparison (<) on that end of the range, rather than an inclusive *less than or equals* (<=) or BETWEEN. This approach is known as *Half-Open*.

So you would do this:

```
WHERE myColumn >= @StartDate and myColumn < DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate)
```

Rather than this:

```
WHERE myColumn BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Or, in this case, set the `@EndDate` like so:

```
declare @Date datetime 
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate Datetime

set @date = current_timestamp
Set @StartDate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@date),0)
set @EndDate = DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@date as date))
```

And then, again, use an *exclusive boundary* on the end of the range:

```
WHERE myColumn >= @StartDate and myColumn < @EndDate
```

---

If you *really* need to get the last instant of the day (and again: it's usually *less effective* and *less precise*), you **still** start by adding one day to the beginning of your target day. Then, you can subtract whatever amount you need (second, millisecond, 3.33 ms tick, etc) from there.